# Image swapping after a number of seconds

Tags: android

I want to swap the image currently in my imageview after 5 seconds but the methods I have tried aren't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my imageview

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/message_sent_indicator"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

What would be the simplest way for me to change this.

```
            02-23 16:49:15.109  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/libc﹕ pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x5013ee31, tls=0x54a77f00, arg=0x51e3c1c0
02-23 16:49:15.119  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54a78000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:75
02-23 16:49:15.119  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4082a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:77
02-23 16:49:15.119  22171-22231/com.mycompany.messaging D/libc﹕ pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x5013ee31
    , tls=0x54a77f00, arg=0x51e3c1c0
02-23 16:49:15.180  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54ccb000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:79
02-23 16:49:15.180  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40919000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:81
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54ec9000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:83
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x50026000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:85
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x53b76000 size:2088960
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40007000 size:4096
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54317000 size:2088960
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4003e000 size:4096
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54725000 size:2088960
02-23 16:49:15.220  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40078000 size:4096
02-23 16:49:20.075  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d0c468)
02-23 16:49:20.085  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mycompany.messaging.ConversationView$1.run(ConversationView.java:58)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ killProcess, pid=22171
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:944)
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
02-23 16:49:22.808  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
02-23 16:49:22.818  22171-22171/com.mycompany.messaging D/Process﹕ dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my onCreate method

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String thread = intent.getStringExtra("threadId");

        threadId = Integer.parseInt(thread);

        write_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.write_a_message);
        post_message_button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.send_message_button);

        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.message_sent_indicator);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            }
        }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds

        final ListView convoListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.conversationListView);

        final ArrayList<ConversationItem> convoItems = this.GetItems(threadId);

        final ConversionAdapter convoAdapter = new ConversionAdapter
                (this, R.layout.conversation_list_item, convoItems);

        post_message_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conversation_username2);

                convoItems.add(new ConversationItem(1656, 1, 888, "Bill Smith", DateTime.now(), write_message.getText().toString()));

                convoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (v.getId() == R.id.send_message_button);
                write_message.setText("");

            }
        });
        convoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        });

        convoListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        convoListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                final int checkedCount = convoListView.getCheckedItemCount();
                mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Message selected");
                convoAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
            }


            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                        // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                        SparseBooleanArray selected = convoAdapter
                                .getSelectedIds();
                        // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                                ConversationItem selecteditem = convoAdapter
                                        .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                                // Remove selected items following the ids
                                convoAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                            }
                        }
                        // CAB
                        mode.finish();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;

                }
            }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a proper app log output.Try restarting your IDE.

Comment: use `Timer` and `Animation` to make a slide show

Answer (score 1):

Use a handler to delay the action:

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.message_sent_indicator);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        iv.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.some_image_id));
    }
}, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds
```

**Edit:**

`getDrawable` is an activity method, but it's available only for API 21+.

The old method is available on a `Resource` instance:

```
myimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Comment: instead of creating a new handler, op could use the view's internal handler?

Comment: @Blackbelt correct, that would be `iv.postDelayed()`.

Comment: Would I replace         iv.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.some_image_id));
with
iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

Comment: unfortunately that gives me a NullPointerException

Comment: @Sim you should learn to read the errors yourself. Post the error message and the line where it occurs. Also did you replace the `ic_launcher` with your image id?

Comment: Sorry for taking up alot of your time, I have an ic_launcher image in my drawables which I am testing it with. I have updated the logcat.

Comment: @Sim well then post your error message. I don't think you're getting an NPE cause of `getDrawable`.

Comment: I have put my error in in place of my last error, I'm not sure but the app works without using the image change I want to implement

Comment: @Sim what's on line ConversationView.java:58 ? Also please post more of your activity's code where you're calling this.

Comment: @Sim I know. But the number (58) refers to specific line. What is on that line in your code?

Comment: This is on line 58                 iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

Comment: @Sim alright. As I've said post more code around that line.

Comment: Sorry I've just added that to my question above

Comment: @Sim post your full `activity_conversation_view.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

use [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method of [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) as this:

```
int delay = 3000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //swap image
                    }
                }, delay);
```

Method must be called in Main thread of your activity.